# Из глуби / изглуби вылез

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Как правильно?

Он пришёл из глуби / изглуби океана.

Из глуби / изглуби нёсся звук, похожий на рычание льва.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Он пришёл **из глуби** океана.*  Предлог и существительное.

***Из глуби** нёсся звук, похожий на рычание льва.*  Наречное выражение.

Нет наречного выражения или предлога ***"изглуби",*** написание только раздельное.

[**Нацкорпус**](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cj8qGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHAoaChgKA3JlcRIRCg/QmNC3INCz0LvRg9Cx0LgwAQ==)

*А вот придёт пора — и все мы разом выступим **из глуби моря**, как Тридцать Три богатыря...* (А. И. Солженицын. Бодался теленок с дубом, 1967-1974)

Comment: Sharon, подправил только ссылку на Нацкорпус. У вас почему-то она открывалась на 14 текстов, у меня на 25.

Comment: Спасибо, я ее исправляла, да, видно, неудачно.

Answer (score 3):

В ваших предложениях, конечно же, надо писать раздельно (глубь — из глуби, глубина — из глубины).

Но — язык наш полон неологизмов.

**Изглуби** — такое слово в качестве наречия использует писатель [Вадим Сухачевский](https://bookmix.ru/authors/index.phtml?id=464):

*— Благодарю тебя, сын мой, за это напоминание, — сказал комтур; фон Штраубе показалось, что тот **изглуби** над ним насмехнулся;

Кожа на ее лице была почти прозрачной, словно ее подсвечивали откуда-то **изглуби**.*

Использует и известный автор [Анатолий Байбородин](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) (интересный слог у него — деревенский, простецкий, "картино-представляющий"):

> А может быть, старик, который неведомо когда и красовался перед зеркалом, загляделся, не узнавая, на своё отражение в воде… по-младенчески растопыренные уши и по-младенчески же вьющиеся подле ушей бело-пушистые остатние волосы; утекающий в пегую плешь изморщиненный лоб, под крутяком которого хоронились, посвечивали **изглуби**, как два махоньких синеньких озерушка, дедовы слезливые глаза… и это отражённое лицо, может быть, приблазнилось старику замершим ликом святого Угодничка Николы, рыбачьего обережителя, который поманил, поманил деда…

Думаю, что на образование особенного слова повлияла пара *и́здали — из дали*.
Мне слово понравилось, оно в этих примерах — к месту.
Может, когда-нибудь и в словари попадет.

Comment: Добавлю пару примеров. Мне  понравилось у Маковского: «_**изглуби звучавшим чувством**_».

Есть _изглуби_ и  у Солженицына — и даже не наречие, а в значении существительного: «_вытянуть кусок жизни **из того изглуби**, что и психологией украшать не надо_»…

Comment: «_В ваших предложениях, конечно же, надо писать раздельно_…» === Ну а почему во втором примере нужно раздельное? Сравните «изглуби нёсся» с «издали слышался».  По-моему, весьма похожие случаи… 

Comment: Вполне возможно, что очень даже похоже. Но в словарях оно не зафиксировано. Напишет в сочинении старшеклассник оригинальное слово, и получит на полях (или где там сейчас их ставят-отмечают) "красную лапту" (**І** – орфографическая ошибка).  *Quod licet Jovi, non licet bovi*.

Comment: Думаю, Sharon правее: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8.%2C+%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8.&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=3, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%2C%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=3.

Comment: Сравнение с *издали* не очень: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%2C+%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=3.